# Is `ClassA c = new ClassB` declaration possible?

Tags: c#

I wonder if this is possible at all in C#:

```
ClassA c = new ClassB();
```

I get it why the right part has to have the class name, but then the left part doesn't have to have the class name (`var c = new Anything()`), so my guess is that it may be possible to create an instance of some class in this unusual way by explicitly typing the names of different (probably connected somehow) classes on the left and right of this expression. Am I wrong?

Comment: You should probably have a look at `inheritance`. Your code is correct if `ClassB` derives from `ClassA`.

Comment: @Chips_100 then what's the purpose of declaring it this way?

Comment: I guess there might be a lot of situations when this could make sense. for example, if you maintain a `List` of `ClassA` instances, and you need to add a `ClassB` instance to it. One might argue, that this way it would look clearer that the created instance of `ClassB` will be treated together with instances of `ClassA`.

Comment: @Chips_100 usually the list would quietly accept a derived class instance, so I don't really get why it would be written this way other than for readability

Comment: @user1306322 pls see answer below on why it is used in that way...

Comment: That's why i tried to be careful, saying `One might argue`. Cant really think of a situation where declaring it this way would be preferrable. I would probably keep the most specific class as long as possible, for example until returning it from a method with a less specific return type.

Comment: I might argue :) - I'm using it all the time - have various service implementations and am trying to initialize concrete classes through constructor just to make further communication as clean as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Purpose of declaring it that way is the same as declaring it with

```
ISomeInterface x=new ClassThatImplementsSomeInterface();
```

and that is to hide everything extra that new class has to offer and 'talk' to the object instance only using interface methods.

Your `ClassA` needs to be base of `ClassB`.

Edit:

Most of the literature will tell you that derivation can be, in English, told and written down as *IS*, as in:

```
 ClassB *IS* ClassA
 ClassThatImplementsSomeInterface *IS* ISomeInterface
```

in this manner, your declaration/assignment is completely correct.

Comment: So is this the same as `((ISomeInterface)new ClassThatImplementsSomeInterface())` ?

Comment: totally.  there is no need to cast 'upwards', EVER

Comment: Makes sense! I think I actually could use that in my project.

Answer (score 9):

Well you could have something like

```
public interface ITADA
{
}

public class BaseTADA : ITADA
{
}

public class TADA : BaseTADA
{
}
```

and then

```
ITADA t1 = new TADA();
BaseTADA t2 = new TADA();
TADA t3 = new TADA();
```

This also allows you to do

```
List<ITADA> list = new List<ITADA>() 
        { 
            new TADA(), 
            new BaseTADA()
        };
```

You should have a look at

[Polymorphism (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

It's even possible through operator overloading:

```
class A
{
}

class B
{
    public static implicit operator A(B b)
    {
        return new A();
    }
}

A a = new B();
```

or

```
class A
{
    public static implicit operator A(B b)
    {
        return new A();
    }
}

class B
{
}

A a = new B();
```

They are [implicit conversions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09479473.aspx).

Note that they aren't connected to polymorphism. They are totally separate (orthogonal, not opposite!)